# WP site keeps getting hacked for a cryptojacker - How to find the leak?

Tags: wordpress, security, firewall

I've got a site that has been hacked for the fourth time now this month. With scripts hosted on `autofaucet.org`. (sloppy code even, found their names. Some Russian dudes. But that's off topic) I've taken some measurements to prevent a new hack, but alas...

- I've installed a clean WP installation on the server, with clean files and a clean DB.
- reinstalled the plugins clean
- I have `All In One WP Security & Firewall` plugin for file scanning, firewall, hide inlog page, etc.
- Changed all the wordpress passwords.

I've notices the encoded code is being placed in files called `assets.php`.

I'm curious how a hacker would inject/place the code on the server. How to prevent it better and what questions to ask the webhost company. I've asked them before and they just say it's my fault, update the wp installation and move on. What should they check if the code is injected from their side?

Comment: Disable WP plugins. They are usually to blame if you keep the main WP updated.

Comment: You could put your Wordpress instance behind a WAF-style appliance to detect and trap a great deal of these compromise attempts.

Comment: Do you mean ALL plugins? Wouldn't that make the idea of WP obsolete? Besides, I only have a few of the usual suspects running.

Comment: @esqew Woah, that's new for me. I'll have to look into WAF and contact the webhost for that

Answer (score 0):

Your log files (of the web server) e.g. `/var/log/nginx/access.log` with the `nginx` web server will tell you who it was. Look for the change date/time of the `assets.php` file. Then check server access logs for IP addresses from that exact time.  Then search logs for that IP address. You will find the first accesses by that IP address.  That was likely the hack.

Usually Wordpress plugins are to blame as long as you keep the WP site updated.  So, you could disable plugins not needed urgently, and disable the others one by one, or all for testing.

As a workaround, you can make the `index.php` (or other) file under attack read-only.  In the past I have worked around particular attacks by `chown root.root filetobeattacked.php` which usually works (but may hinder updates, so it's a temporary solution). If you are not `root` on the server (shared hosting) perhaps `chmod 444 filetobeattacked.php` could work.

Comment: Hmm no logs on the moment of the change timestamp. I did find somthing one minute after one file and 2 minutes before the other file.`IP.IP.IP.IP - - [14/Dec/2021:16:24:11 +0100] "POST //xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 403 4648 "http://www.google.com.hk" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36"
IP.IP.IP.IP- - [14/Dec/2021:16:24:40 +0100] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 404 48925 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"`

Comment: Those look like attack attempts. The access could be slightly before the file modification date.  Does a search reveal earlier access attempts?  Perhaps include `error.log` in the search, though the attack must be in `access.log`.  Have you also tried the workarounds?

Comment: The error log have several of these lines. All by different IPs `[Tue Dec 14 16:11:40.995067 2021] [authz_core:error] [pid 754409:tid 140036511090432] [client IP:62387] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/mydomain/domains/mydomain.nl/private_html/xmlrpc.php, referer: http://www.google.com.hk`
I've now changed the affected `index.php` in the wp root folder to permission 444. Removed the assets file. It's being installed in serveral locations. Removed and placed somewhere else every time. In `wp-includes` and the theme folder. These are not pre-existing files I can set to 444

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue before. It might be the wordpress core files.

1. Delete all files except wp-content, then download and replace it with the new wordpress files.
2. Search for 'autofaucet.org' inside wp-content, and remove if necessary.
3. Open wp-contents/themes/ then check functions.php - check if any additional code is there on top. Check the last updated files and time inside the theme and plugins.
4. Export database files and searcg for 'autofaucet.org' and remove if any item found.

Comment: Generate and replace with new keys from wordpress codex (wp-config)

https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/

Comment: Thanks, I've already done the above. The salt keys where new for me. I've installed a plugin called saltshaker to automatically change the keys daily. The search would (I think not work) since the code is encoded (I think base64). But I don't know how to decode the infected encoded code to see how the code works and what it does :)

Comment: Just remove the code. There is some way to convert it to a code to readable form. Can you post that string here ? I can encode it for you.

Comment: Thanks Rayan, I've posted it here: https://pastebin.com/bW9uUBUv The code is available for two weeks. If you succeed I would be very interested to learn from it.

Comment: HI Tim. Its giving me Not Found (#404)

Comment: Hmm admins must have deleted it. Here is a new link with a not so descriptive title: https://pastebin.com/nMAQHXX4